# Вопрос, который отображается как пример на странице Тура, был впоследствии закрыт. Может его следует заменить?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тур

В виде примера отображается старая версия [вот этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41062/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). Вопрос был опубликован в 2011 году и затем закрыт в 2015.

Некоторые критерии вопросов подходящих как примерные для тура можно найти [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page/163948).

Возможно этот вопрос в начале существования сайта считался достаточно качественным, но с моей точки зрения он больше подошёл бы для SuperUser (хотя даже там он был бы слишком обширным), чем для StackOverflow, так как вопрос, по сути, не о программировании, а о выборе подхода к решению проблемы связанной с использованием не уточнённого устройства при помощи железа, а не софта.

Возможно, следует заменить его на более качественный открытый вопрос, соответствующий современным стандартам сайта? Какой по вашему мнению вопрос мог бы стать хорошей заменой?

Comment: Думаю, можно ваш вопрос отредактировать и попросить участников сообщества выбрать интересный по их мнению вопрос, а потом уже голосованием решим. Или отдельным постом это сделать, а здесь пока просто обсудить, нужно это делать или нет.

Comment: Да, звучит как две разных темы. Если считаете нужным, можно разделить мой вопрос на два. Я тогда останусь с этим а кто-нибудь еще может задать второй.

Comment: В этом вопросе пока просто в общем обсудим. А если решим менять, я отдельный вопрос потом задам.

Comment: Верните пони с маргаритками!)

Answer (score 5):

В общем-то, идея интересная.

1. Вопрос старый, закрытый. Возможно не самый лучший для Тура в принципе.
2. Сообщество меняется, мнение меняется. Вполне логично периодически менять.
3. В принципе, можно вообще раз в месяц выбирать лучший вопрос и добавлять его на страницу Тура.